# AEM 6.0 Performance Tunning checklist for Production

Tags: aem

AEM 6.0 Performance Tunning checklist for Production with steps? Please don't give step provided by Adobe offical site as i'm using CRX3 with AEM 6.0 and i refer these points but unable to find the files  like workspace.xml and repository.xml as these file are in crx2?

Answer (score 0):

you have seen this http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/configuring/performance.html and this https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/performance-tuning-tips.html already right?

Comment: ok great, I will start to tease some more info out of you bit-by-bit. 

So you have said you are using CRX3, what is your runtime params you are using? Are you using Lucien or Solr? Are you using MongoDB?

Yes workspace and repository XML files are from CRX2 the new configs are stored in the repository and OSGI config.

Oak ref: http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/
MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/optimization/

Comment: Have you seen this: http://tech.ethomasjoseph.com/2015/03/tuning-your-jcr-queries-for-aem.html